# Install and configure Debug Diagnostics tool on 100 servers

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012, diagnostics

I am using ansible to deploy Debug Diagnostics tool msi package to 100 servers, however I need to export configuration for IIS. I can not do that manually and I could not find any CLI or powershell script to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

[Debug Diagnostic Tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EpgD.png)

Comment: Debug Diagnostics is not a tool that you should widely distributed inside your server farm. Why do you want to do so? If your goal is to merely capture dumps, there are tons of other tools.

Comment: Our stack application uses W2K and IIS so we need to capture dumps whenever IIS crashes, any other suggestion ?

Comment: In the past decades, Microsoft introduced WER which is a built-in Windows feature, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/using-wer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should help

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/06/27/installing-debugdiag-and-importing-rules-thru-azure-cloud-services-startup-tasks/

This is what I was looking for

"%ProgramFiles%\DebugDiag\DebugDiag.Collection.exe" /importConfig %~dp0DebugDiagRule.ddconfig –DoNotPrompt